# Vhost and Debugging with 127.0.0.1:8888

Tags: php, apache, drupal, xdebug, vhosts

I have a Drupal application that runs using the following command "drush runserver"

When I run this command, I get the following message: "HTTP server listening on 127.0.0.1, port 8888 (see http://127.0.0.1:8888/)"

If I visit that url, I see the application I am supposed to see, so that is good.

However, I am trying to create a vhost to this url as well as do some debugging on the application.

I've created vhosts many times before, but never for an application that lives on another port. After doing some google searches, I have placed the following in my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8888

<VirtualHost *:8888>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/justin/Sites/drupal/"
    ServerName myproject.dev
    ServerAlias www.myproject.dev
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/myproject.dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/myproject.dev-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also placed the following in my /etc/hosts file.

127.0.0.1       myproject.dev www.myproject.dev

And even after restarting my server, if I visit myproject.dev in my browser window, the browser just hangs. Like I said, I've never had problems doing this before, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the 8888. Any solutions for this?

Secondly, I am trying to set up debugging for my application in PHPStorm. Again, I have a feeling the reason I am having so much trouble is because of the 8888 port. I must be missing something that I usually do not have to set when I debug normally (port 80).

Here are my current xdebug settings in my php.ini file:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php55-xdebug/2.4.0/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1:8888"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey="phpstorm"
xdebug.max_nesting_level=1000
```

And I should mention that my debugger works with any random PHP file I make outside of the project. Again, I must be missing something with this 8888 port.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with three different things here. First is the built in PHP web server that is spinning up with Drush. It listens on port 8888 unless you specify differently on the command line. Second is Apache and a vhost configuration. You can leave the vhost listening on port 80. The port is selected by the server not the application. You can run the server on port 16421 and your app will work just fine. Third is your xdebug config.

The only real problem I see is your xdebug config. You only need the remote host IP/hostname not the additional port. The port you have added there is the port used by PHP's built in web server. Xdebug runs on a different port which is defined in the xdebug config xdebug.remote_port setting. PHPStorm is going to be configured to connect to xdebug on that specific port, . Make sure the ports in PHPStorm and your xdebug config match.

If you have it configured correctly, it won't matter if you are using the built in web server or Apache, you will be able to debug.